# ORA-00932:inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g on ubuntu 14.04LTS. I have a table called members which I created by the following sql,

```
 create table members(
    mem_id int,
    issue_date date,
    expire_date date,
    book_count int,
    fine float(2),
    mem_pic bfile,
    CONSTRAINT mem_const PRIMARY KEY (mem_id)
 );
```

Later on I have updated the table like this,

```
alter table members add( mem_pic bfile ) ;
```

Now when I run "DESC members" it shows the result,

> ```
> Name                     Null?    Type
>  ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
>  MEM_ID                  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
>  ISSUE_DATE                       DATE
>  EXPIRE_DATE                      DATE
>  BOOK_COUNT                       NUMBER(38)
>  FINE                             FLOAT(2)
>  MEM_PIC                          BINARY FILE LOB
> ```

Finally I run a insert sql like this,

```
SQL> insert into members( MEM_id ,MEM_PIC ) values(4,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('/home/pictures/images.jpeg'));
```

It shows the error,

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER
>   got BINARY

Can anybody help me where is the problem.
And I am also not sure weather in this process I can add the binary file of the image or the path.Can anybody help me on that how I can update my table with the image from the following path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`utl_raw.cast_to_raw` returns a `raw`

(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_raw.htm#BABJHEGF)

while you need a `BFILE`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96591/adl12bfl.htm#79488